# how to alternate continously Signal handler

Tags: c, linux, signals, handler

I want to write a program in c for linux that  catchs the first SIGUSR1 signal, ignores the second one and continue in this behaviour (catch-ignore) for the successive SIGUSR1 signals.

I wonder how to keep  alternating  between the two handlers, because once i set the handler to SIG_IGN, the signal will be ignored and  I won't be able to detect it and act accordingly.

This is the code i have tried:

```
int tst;
void sigusr1_handler(){
   if(tst==0){
      signal(SIGUSR1,SIG_IGN);
      tst=1;
    } 
   else tst= 0;
}


int main(){
   signal(SIGUSR1, sigusr1_handler);
   tst=1;
   while(1){}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ignoring a signal (usually) results in program termination.  Suggest: always catch the signal, and use a 'static' variable to determine if the code will do anything with the current instance of the signal.  I.E. the signal handler function checks/updates the static variable with each signal received.

Comment: the problem is that I need to alternate with SIG_IGN. If I catch the signal with a signal handler function, that function won't be excuted once the signal handler is set to SIG_IGN for the first time.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I edited the post and i added the code i tried

Comment: If using `SIG_IGN` on the desired signal, then your program will never see the signal, so it cannot know when that signal has arrived, so it will not know when to re-enable the signal.   Suggest re-thinking the problem.

Comment: Note: per the man page for `signal()` : "The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also varied historically across different versions of Linux.   Avoid  its  use: use sigaction(2) instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not.

What you can do, is have your signal handler decide whether to do something or not -- for example, whether to call an another function or not. This is not completely reliable, however, because [standard POSIX signals](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) like `SIGUSR1` are not queued. If two or more signals are sent at (nearly) the same time, only one is actually delivered. POSIX realtime signals (`SIGRTMIN+0` to `SIGRTMAX-0` -- from the programmer's point of view, only the number and semantics differ) are queued, but even they can be dropped in some situations.

In all cases, remember that a signal handler function can only use [async-signal safe functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). If you need to be able to use all functions, you should instead block the signals in all threads, and have a dedicated thread receive the signals using e.g. [`sigwaitinfo()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html). In this case, you don't have signal handler functions, but instead a dedicated thread that *receives* the signals, and is thus free to use any functions it wants.

If we reword the question into *"How do I alternate the handling of a delivered signal in a single-threaded program?"*, the answer is simple: you use a `volatile sig_atomic_t` counter.

For alternating between two choices, `do_something_odd()` first:

```
#include <signal.h>

void my_signal_handler(int signum)
{
    static volatile sig_atomic_t  count = 0;

    switch (++count) {

    case 1:
        do_something_odd();
        break;

    default:
        count = 0;
        do_something_even();
        break;
    }
}
```

For alternating between three cases, you add more `case` statements as necessary:

```
#include <signal.h>

void my_signal_handler(int signum)
{
    static volatile sig_atomic_t  count = 0;

    switch (++count) {

    case 2:
        do_something_2_of_3();
        break;

    case 1:
        do_something_1_of_3();
        break;

    default:
        count = 0;
        do_something_3_of_3()           
        break;
    }
}
```

The above assumes you install the signal handler using [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) without `SA_SIGINFO` in `.sa_flags`.

The POSIX standard says you can do up to 128 cases (as `sig_atomic_t` is guaranteed to be able to represent values `0` to `127`, inclusive) this way.

You can do larger sets using an `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`, but then you must NOT have `SA_NODEFER` in the `.sa_flags`, and if the same handler is used for multiple signals, the `.sa_mask` must have all the other signals handled by the same handler set. This ensures that the signal handler is not interrupted by another signal that is delivered to the same handler, and allows us to use non-atomic counter variable.

In a multithreaded program one must rely on compiler-provided atomic operations, either legacy [`__sync`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html) built-ins, or [`__atomic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) built-ins. They are not GCC-specific; at least Intel Compiler Collection and clang provide them also. For alternating between two options, `our = __atomic_xor_fetch(&counter, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);` or `our = __sync_xor_and_fetch(&counter, 1);` can be used to obtain and flip a counter between 0 and 1 atomically. For a non-power-of-two number of options, a compare-and-swap loop is typically used.